# php arrays - in_array and/or array_intersect

Tags: php, arrays

It's another day for being thick—so sorry. :) Anyhow, I have 2 arrays that I want to manipulate; if a value from the first array exists in the second array do one thing and then do something else with the remaining values of the second array.

e.g.

```
$array1 = array('1','2','3','4'); - the needle
$array2 = array('1','3','5','7'); - the haystack

if(in_array($array1,$array2): echo 'the needle'; else: echo'the haystack LESS the needle '; endif;
```

But for some reason the `in_array` doesn't work for me. Help please.

Comment: Do you mean that "any value" or "all values" from the needle must be present in the haystack?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do it like this:

```
<?php
$array1 = array('1','2','3','4');
$array2 = array('1','3','5','7');

//case 1:
print_r(array_intersect($array1, $array2));

//case 2:
print_r(array_diff($array2, $array1));
?>
```

This outputs the values of array (what you wanted earlier before question was changed):

```
Array
(
    [0] => 1
    [2] => 3
)
Array
(
    [2] => 5
    [3] => 7
)
```

---

**And, if you want to use `if-else`, do it like this:**

```
<?php
$array1 = array('1','2','3','4');
$array2 = array('1','3','5','7');

$intesect = array_intersect($array1, $array2);

if(count($intesect))
{
    echo 'the needle';
    print_r($intesect);
}
else
{
    echo'the haystack LESS the needle ';
    print_r(array_diff($array2, $array1));
}
?>
```

This outputs:

```
the needle
Array
(
    [0] => 1
    [2] => 3
)
```

Comment: Thanks shamittomar - said was being think, I couldn't get the first array into the array_diff as I had previously manipulated it somehow (forgotten now) as your code works a dream

Comment: If this is literally what you want, then `array_diff` is completely superfluous since you've already determined that the intersection is null.

Comment: @konforce, yes I agree but in the original question (which is now revised) it was asked to show the remaining values.